# css menu inline-block not working

Tags: navbar, css

I have a css menu i'm working on.  I'm trying to get the menu items inline, however, it they always display vertically instead.  I've tried putting `display:inline-block` on all of the elements and it still doesn't want to go inline.  Any suggestions? Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/3aShL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<li>`s are block-level items, so just because the `<a>` is, still means with every `<li>` you will get a new line.

http://jsfiddle.net/3aShL/1/

```
display: inline;
```

On the `.nav-collapse_ .nav > li` will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to css

```
li
{
display:inline;
}
```

display:inline; - By default, li elements are block elements. Here, we remove the line breaks before and after each list item, to display them on one line

[**Demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/3aShL/2/)